# Memory leak tomcat 7

Tags: memory-leaks, tomcat7

when I run my Tomcat 7 I get this error message :

```
Aug 04, 2015 12:53:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads 
SEVERE: The web application [/sample] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#5_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should gracefully shutdown quartz within a ServletContextListener like this one:

```
public class AppListener implements ServletContextListener
{

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)
{
    try
    {
        WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
        Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) context.getBean("quartzSchedulerFactory");
        scheduler.shutdown(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)
{
}
```

You have to add these ServletContextListener in your web.xml. You should place your listener at the first position in your web.xml because on tomcat runs the listeners in a reverse order on shutdown.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>yourpackage.AppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Alternatively you could shutdown the scheduler within a method annotated with @PreDestroy

Answer (score 0):

SchedulerFactoryBean has had a flag to tell it to wait for jobs to complete since at least Spring 3.0. Set the flag and make sure the destroy method will be called at shutdown:

```
<bean id="scheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    ....
```

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(boolean)